# Accessing HiddenField inside the datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using a Datalist to show countries list each record having a Gridview containing a list of states and each state having a Dropdownlist for cities. I am using a hidden field to get the ID of country to retrieve the name of state for every record by using Eval("C_ID") in the hidden field. But it raises ArgumentOutOfRangeException. I'm not able to know what I'm doing wrong. 
Here is the code for Datalist:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" >
        <ItemTemplate>
        <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%#Eval("C_Name") %><br />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%#Eval("C_ID") %>' runat="server" />
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State   Cities">
                                <ItemTemplate >
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                                    <%#Eval("S_Name") %>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

and this is code behind:

```
public partial class AdvancedTable : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Country", con);
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds, "Country");
            con.Close();
            DataList1.DataSource = ds;
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da2.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from State where C_ID='"+((HiddenField)DataList1.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value+"'",con);
        con.Open();
        da2.Fill(ds, "State");
        con.Close();
        ((GridView)e.Item.FindControl("GridView1")).DataSource = ds.Tables["State"];
        ((GridView)e.Item.FindControl("GridView1")).DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nathan thanks for rectifying my mistake, could you tell me something about this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, instead of `DataList1.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("HiddenField1")`

Just use `e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1")`

Comment: Oh yes, it was right. Probably I had some misconception although a minor one. Thanks Chrisb.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can do the following:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSource="<%# GetList((int)Eval("C_ID"))%>">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In the code Behind

```
protected DataTable GetList(int id){ }
```

Comment: Actaully, for the states I don't want Dropdownlist, this may be okay with the cities list. I want to know why the exception is being raised?